# Ignore tables while parsing PDF

Tags: python, pdf, xml-parsing, pypdf, pdfminer

I want to parse pdf and remove all tables , images . i have used PyPDF2 and pdfminer to parse the pdf but it also parses contents of the tables along with other content. I tried to convert pdf to xml(using pdfminer) to get some structure so that I can ignore tables . But i got no useful structure. i got  element with different id's like this

```
 <textbox id="1" bbox="56.760,740.908,82.824,751.816">
```

and I know,  I can use these id attribute to ignore this table but I have a large set of documents and using this approach i have to manually check which id belongs to table so that i can ignore it. I there any other way to automate this task ?

[Here is](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18dPf_WHUG6pJcEd3bzF3dzKM7ueojlnX?usp=sharing) sample pdf and xml file.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced a similar problem. I wanted to ignore tables and charts. Since my table and charts had mostly numerical data I chose the below method.
1. Extract text using tika.
2. Split the text into sentences.
3. Use stopwords as reference and filter out those sentences which doesn't contain at least one stopword.(a sentence is impossible without having any one  preposition)

This solved the problem to a great extent. ALso we could get rid of footers, passage titles upto a certain extent using this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to extract texts containing "pdf markdown" and then parse it using your favorite tool (like regular expressions) to skip tables:

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

pdf_markdown = ""

try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass

text = my_cool_tables_parser(pdf_markdown)
```

Comment: please help share the my_cool_tables_parser function code

Comment: @gosgenq `my_cool_tables_parser` is your custom parser here. you should code it.

Comment: can you give me some pointers on how to skip the table with regular expression. I am getting the following result on executing the above code.
0.750000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.750000 0.000000 841.920044 cm q 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg BT 0 Tr /F1 14.720600 Tf 1 0 0.000000 -1 96.000000 109.919998 Tm [(L) -) -6.000000 ( ) -0.074219] TJ ET Q q 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg BT 0 Tr /F2 14.720600 Tf 1 0 0.000000 -1 502.559998 109.919998 Tm [( ) -0.074219] TJ ET

Comment: @gosgenq Read p 9.3 Text State Parameters and Operators. https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Answer (score 0):

can you give me some pointers on how to skip the table with regular expression. I am getting the following result on executing the above code.
0.750000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.750000 0.000000 841.920044 cm
q
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg
BT
0 Tr
/F1 14.720600 Tf
1 0 0.000000 -1 96.000000 109.919998 Tm
[(L) -0.851563 (i) -0.605469 (s) -12.000000 (t) 16.000000 ( ) -0.074219 (o) -0.597656 (f) -0.406250 ( ) -0.074219 (R) -8.000000 (e) -0.417969 (p) 6.000000 (o) 7.000000 (r) -0.468750 (t) -0.679688 (a) -0.652344 (b) 6.000000 (l) -0.605469 (e) -7.000000 ( )  6.000000 (o) 7.000000 (r) -0.468750 (t) -0.679688 (i) -0.605469 (n) 6.000000 (g) -6.000000 ( ) -0.074219] TJ
ET
Q
q
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg
BT
0 Tr
/F2 14.720600 Tf
1 0 0.000000 -1 502.559998 109.919998 Tm
[( ) -0.074219] TJ
ET